# Socket.io on specific endpoint

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I'm learning how to use [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). My website is built on Node.js and express. In this site, I have a number of views. However, I only want to use sockets on one specific view `/dashboard/stream`. In other words, I only want to turn on sockets if something visits `/dashboard/stream`. All of the documentation I read implies that I need to configure sockets at the app level in express. In other words, it looks like it's always on. So, if someone uses my website, but never visits `/dashboard/stream`, sockets would still be running on the server.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to say "if someone visits `/dashboard/stream` activate sockets for the user?

Thank you for helping me gain clarity on this.

Comment: What do you mean activate socket?
It will run always on the level of the application, you can subscribe to it or not. Can you clarify the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io requires access to the underlying HTTP server object that backs express.

So in simplest form, as I'm sure you probably checked out on docs you attach a socket.io Server to Express using something like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

So its designed so that you're effectively *binding* it to the http server, and then proceed with doing `io.on`, `io.emit` and all that stuff. Now as far as where you put the code for actually binding socket.io to express, I'm guessing you could place it anywhere you want, if you don't want with all initial setup, and then simply define your socket.on at the specific route in route handler.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've setup what you mentioned above. However, I'm unsure how to setup listening on a specific endpoint. For example, I have `var s = io('/dashboard/stream');  s.on('client-connected', function (data) { console.log(data); });` in my HTML page. Then, in my Node `app, I have: app.get('/dashboard/stream', function(req, res) { app.io.on('connection', function(socket) { socket.emit('client-connected', { text: 'A client connected!' }); });`. However, I never see a response on the client side.

Comment: I also added `s.on('connect', function(){ console.log(s.id);  });` in my HTML page as mentioned in the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket). However, it seems the `connect` event never gets triggered.

Comment: ok... I got the communication working between the client and server. However, I only have it working on the root. I can't seem to figure out how to get it working specifically via the endpoint /dashboard/stream which was my original question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see, well some things that stand out is that you shouldn't really have a path in `var s = io()` it should be just kept as that on client-side. Did that fix it? Let me make an edit to my answer to try show an example where you would only do it on the particular endpoint. But the idea as I mentioned, is that socket.io _has_ to bind to an instance of http server. So a way around that so you're not really listening everywhere is just move the io.on code inside a route handler that you want, that way it would only do stuff if io events happen while on that route.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to implement listening on an endpoint is namespaces.

```
const nsp= io.of('/admin');

nsp.use((socket, next) => {
  // ensure the user has sufficient rights
  next();
});

nsp.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('delete user', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v3/namespaces/#Custom-namespaces